# Apache Cxf Wsdl2java Create Web Service Client Encoding Error

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I tried to create web service client, then I am seeing that encoding error.

I changed the eclipse encoding property, JVM encoding property and file encoding property and set UTF-8, but that does not change anything!

```
    WSDLToJava Error: Schema Error : s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'attributeFormDefault' in element 'schema'. Recorded reason: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'unqualıfıed' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '(qualified | unqualified)'. It must be a value from the enumeration.

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Schema Error : s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'attributeFormDefault' in element 'schema'. Recorded reason: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'unqualıfıed' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '(qualified | unqualified)'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.validateSchema(JAXBDataBinding.java:911)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.addSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:588)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:391)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:589)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:139)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'attributeFormDefault' in element 'schema'. Recorded reason: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'unqualıfıed' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '(qualified | unqualified)'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSAttributeChecker.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSAttributeChecker.checkAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSAttributeChecker.checkAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDocumentInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.validateSchema(JAXBDataBinding.java:906)
    ... 10 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it is encoding error?

Comment: Becasue, when i created wsdl and schema, in xsd file  attributeFormDefault attr value seems like "unqualfıed".that isn't  encoding problem?

Comment: Are you in control of WSDL that you are trying to parse?

Comment: I've tested with soap UI and soapclient.com wsdl is correct.

Comment: So, can you change WSDL?

Comment: the same web service project work on linux and i can created client. bu on windows giving this error.

Comment: So just change `unqualıfıed` to `unqualified` and be happy.

Comment: i changed. but does not work :(

Comment: attributeFormDefault defaults to unqualified.   Try removing the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 1):

- Delete **attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified"** line from wsdl
- Change your All Regional Settings United States/Kingdom
- When you import WSDL select **Develop Client** from Apache CXF Wizard